# python multiprocessing Pool.apply() RuntimeError

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying out python multi-processing with a sample example. I am using `Pool.apply()` to get the row wise common items in `list_a` and `list_b`.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

list_a = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7, 8], [10, 11, 12], [20, 21]]
list_b = [[2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14], [21, 24, 25]]

def get_commons(list_1, list_2):
    return list(set(list_1).intersection(list_2))

pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

results = [pool.apply(get_commons, args=(l1, l2)) for l1, l2 in zip(list_a, list_b)]
pool.close()
print(results)
```

This throws following error >

```
An attempt has been made to start a new process before the current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.
```

On searching through similar questions, I tried using `__name__ == '__main__'` as follows -

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = [pool.apply(get_commons, args=(l1, l2)) for l1, l2 in zip(list_a, list_b)]
```

No luck though.

Comment: @Aaron `apply` most certainly does return something, i.e. whatever the worker function (`get_commons`) returns. The problem, however, with the method in this case is that it blocks until the result is ready and so there is no multiprocessing  occurring in the OP's code.

Comment: @Booboo my bad... I was thinking of `apply_async`...

Comment: @Aaron Yes, I realized that after I wrote my comment since `apply` doesn't have callback capability either. I should have just said, "I believe you mean `apply_async`". Oh well. Anyway, the OP did use `apply` so he really wasn't multiprocessing in the truest sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `pool.apply` you are *not* multiprocessing because the `apply` method is a blocking method and will not return until a result is ready and returned. You can call `apply_async`, which returns immediately with an `AsyncResult` instance representing a future result and then you would end up with a list of these. Then you could loop through this list calling `get` on each `AsyncResult` instance to wait for the result to be ready and returned. *That* would be multiprocessing. Or you could call `apply_async` specifying the *callback* argument specifying a function which will be called when the result is ready. Or, as in the code below, you can call `starmap`:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

list_a = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7, 8], [10, 11, 12], [20, 21]]
list_b = [[2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14], [21, 24, 25]]

def get_commons(list_1, list_2):
    return list(set(list_1).intersection(list_2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

    results = pool.starmap(get_commons, zip(list_a, list_b))
    print(results)
```

Prints:

```
[[2, 3], [6], [11, 12], [21]]
```

You will not see any performance improvement, however, with such a trivial worker function as `get_commons` due to the added overhead of creating processes and passing arguments and results between one address space and another.

Here is the code using `pool.apply_async`:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

list_a = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7, 8], [10, 11, 12], [20, 21]]
list_b = [[2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14], [21, 24, 25]]

def get_commons(list_1, list_2):
    return list(set(list_1).intersection(list_2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

    async_results = [pool.apply_async(get_commons, args=(l1, l2)) for l1, l2 in zip(list_a, list_b)]
    results = [async_result.get() for async_result in async_results]
    print(results)
```

And here is the code using a callback:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

list_a = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7, 8], [10, 11, 12], [20, 21]]
list_b = [[2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14], [21, 24, 25]]

def get_commons(list_1, list_2):
    return list(set(list_1).intersection(list_2))

def my_callback(result):
    results.append(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    results = []
    for l1, l2 in zip(list_a, list_b):
        pool.apply_async(get_commons, args=(l1, l2), callback=my_callback)
    # wait for all submitted tasks to complete:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(results)
```

**Note that when using the "callback" technique, results will be added in the order of completion, not necessarily in the order of task submission.**